# How does vector<bool> deal with references and iterators?

Tags: c++, boolean, stdvector, proxy-classes, bitvector

As we all probably know the C++ 98 `vector<bool>` specialization stores boolean values as bits rather than as bool variables. `vector<bool>`'s elements aren't addressable because C++ doesn't have pointers and references to bits, is there a workaround to this, any obvious pitfalls (*that i seem to be oblivious to*) and is it practical to even try and do so?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/8399417/78845

Comment: see this question for related issues http://stackoverflow.com/q/14061694/819272

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vector<bool>`'s elements are addressable as any other `vector`'s elements e.g. with `operator []`. However, the operations will be slower, because of the memory compression.

Maybe faster implementation will use your own inmemory implementation and use binary shifts to address specific boolean value.

Also an alternative will be to use simple array in places where this is appropriate. Remember that you can allocate it dynamically using the `new` operator.

**EDIT** Alternative implementations might be found e.g. in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670308/alternative-to-vectorbool).

Comment: you listed one pitfall as it being slower and alternative(s), i know of alternatives, i'm just trying to see if there is some way to work directly with it. I vaguely remember reading somewhere about a reference, this being a nested class of sorts but i can't seem to find anything on it.

Comment: @iKlsR you can work directly with it as I already pointed out in my answer. You can also look for alternative implementation e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670308/alternative-to-vectorbool

Comment: i seem to be fumbling with my words, thanks for the additional links, what i'm thinking of is http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector-bool/reference/ which would seem to work but i'm not sure how better than the (default [ ]) way it is.

Comment: @iKlsR what kind of operations are you interested in?

Comment: it's in the question, iteration and referencing, don't get me wrong, you have provided an answer, it's just not 'satisfying' enough ;) . I feel there is a special way to do this, im just not asking properly i guess.

Comment: You *can* iterate and you *can* use `std::vector<bool>::reference` as a "proxy" reference. See http://liveworkspace.org/code/1gNZ5O$0 for an example.

Comment: @iKlsR: while iterating, won't you need to also access the value in some way that will allow you to use it in some operations? Most such cases require you to cast to `bool`

Comment: @Boris yes and yes, even tho in this case the raw bits are a tad bit more useful. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of references/pointers to bits, `vector<bool>` uses wrapper objects with overloaded operators that behave (in most cases) like references/pointers to booleans.