# Second order implicit conversion

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, implicit-conversion, conversion-operator

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class first
{
    public:
        constexpr first(bool val) noexcept : _value{val} {}
        constexpr operator bool() const noexcept {return _value;}
    private:
        bool _value;
};

class second
{
    public:
        constexpr second(first val) noexcept : _value{val} {}
        constexpr operator first() const noexcept {return _value;}
    private:
        first _value;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    first f{false};
    second s{true};
    bool b1 = f;
    bool b2 = s; // Not compiling 
    return 0;
}
```

Until recently, I was thinking that the standard and compilers were "clever" enough to find the required conversion sequence when it exists.

In other words, I was thinking that `bool b2 = s` would convert `s` to `first`, and then to `bool`. But apparently it is not happening.

What is the correct approach to obtain an equivalent behaviour for `first` and `second`?

Comment: I know you are writing a proposal for bit-iterators, for reference, see [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14061694/819272) on what the limitations are for such proxy classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible because only a single user-defined conversion is allowed:

> **4 Standard conversions [conv]**
>
> 7 [ Note: For class types, user-defined conversions are considered as
>   well; see 12.3. In general, an implicit conversion sequence (13.3.3.1)
>   consists of a standard conversion sequence followed by a user-defined
>   conversion followed by another standard conversion sequence. — end
>   note ]

as well as

> **12.3 Conversions [class.conv]**
>
> 4 At most one user-defined conversion (constructor or conversion function) is implicitly applied to a single
>   value.

See also Items 5 (Be wary of user-defined conversion functions), 28 (smart pointers) and 30 (proxy classes) of More Effective C++.

For standard conversions (using builtin types), there is no restriction on how many conversions there can be in the sequence.

Comment: I seem to recall that the standardized implementation of old `std::auto_ptr` somehow managed to halfway get around this limit. Sort of.

Comment: No, `std:auto_ptr` didn't have implicit conversion to raw pointer. It just went through an apparent double conversion in order to transfer ownership from an initializer to the declared variable. It had (has, but deprecated) a templated implicit conversion to `auto_ptr_ref`, plus a constructor providing implicit conversion from `auto_ptr_ref`. And that sequence sure *looks* like a double conversion.

Comment: No, I was not thinking of a double conversion sequence, and I was not thinking of `operator->`. In response to your first bafflement I looked it up, and then posted the details, which you now responded to. You could read it before responding, you know.

Comment: I think you should do it yourself. I'm allowing for Sunday-effect and all.

Comment: TemplateRex: At the age of 50+ I still don't know how to discuss things with people who just don't get the simplest things. Who stubbornly persist in their own nonsense beliefs no matter how many times contradicted. So, I'm out of here. You could have learned something. You didn't.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#84

Comment: TemplateRex: that's **dumb**.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf it appears there once was indeed such a loophole. tnx for insisting :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add an `operator bool` to `second`.  The compiler will only look at one user-defined implicit conversion.